# TikZ: Draw in the background of tcolorbox tcboxeditemize

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, layers

Based on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/444384/44634) I would like to add a background around multiple `tcboxeditemize` environments from the [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=de) package. In my MWE the tcboxeditemize rasters remains in the background and I only draw on the `tikz` layers. Is there any chance to get only the big gray rectangle in the background? Putting the whole thing in a `tikzpicture` environment does not seem to work.

---

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    My RectLabel Style/.style={
        draw=black
       ,fill=white
    }
}
%
\tikzset{
    My Bg Style/.style={
        inner xsep=10pt
       ,inner ysep=10pt
       ,draw=black
       ,thick
       ,fill=lightgray % should have this color
       %,fill=none
    }
}
% 
\definecolor{myboxcolor}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\definecolor{myrastercolor}{RGB}{220,220,220}
% 
\tcbset{
    myraster/.style={
        raster columns=#1, 
        raster equal height, 
        size=small, 
        rounded corners, 
        frame hidden,
        colback=myrastercolor,
        halign=center
    },
    mybox/.style={
        colframe=black,
        colback=myboxcolor,
        sharp corners,
        coltitle=black,
        fontupper=\small,
        enhanced,
        attach boxed title to top center={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
        boxed title style={
            colback=white,
            colframe=black,
            sharp corners,
            remember as={title #1},
        },
        title={#1},
        remember as={#1},
        left skip=0.5cm,
        right skip=0.5cm,
    }
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{bg}    % declare background layer
\pgfsetlayers{bg,main}  % set the order of the layers (main is the standard layer)

\begin{tcboxeditemize}%
[%inner boxes properties
    myraster=3
]{%outer box properties
    mybox={Client Layer}
}
    \tcbitem Library 2-1
    \tcbitem Library 2-2
    \tcbitem Library 2-3
    \tcbitem Library 2-4
    \tcbitem Library 2-5
\end{tcboxeditemize}
\vspace*{.5cm}
\begin{tcboxeditemize}%
[%inner boxes properties
    myraster=3
]{%outer box properties
    mybox={Utility Layer}
}
    \tcbitem Library 1-1
    \tcbitem Library 1-2
    \tcbitem Library 1-3
\end{tcboxeditemize}
\vspace*{.5cm}
\begin{tcboxeditemize}%
[%inner boxes properties
    myraster=3
]{%outer box properties
    mybox={Base Layer}
}
    \tcbitem Library 1-1
    \tcbitem Library 1-2
    \tcbitem Library 1-3
\end{tcboxeditemize}

\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{

    \draw[-latex] (title Base Layer) -- (Utility Layer);
    \draw[-latex] (title Utility Layer) -- (Client Layer);


    \begin{pgfonlayer}{bg}    % select the background layer
        \node[fit={(Base Layer) (Client Layer) (title Client Layer)}, My Bg Style] (rect2) {};
        \node[My RectLabel Style,anchor=west] (rect2Label) at ($(rect2.north west)!0.1!(rect2.north east)$) {Lib};
    \end{pgfonlayer} 

}
```

---

### Result

Thanks Ignasi. This is the result I am very pleased with.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{mybgcolor}{RGB}{250,250,250}
\definecolor{myboxcolor}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\definecolor{myrastercolor}{RGB}{220,220,220}

\tcbset{
    myraster/.style={
        raster columns=#1, 
        raster equal height,
        raster row skip=2mm,
        size=small, 
        rounded corners, 
        frame hidden,
        colback=myrastercolor,
        halign=center,
        raster halign=center % center last line if not full
    }
  ,mybox/.style={
        colframe=black,
        colback=myboxcolor,
        sharp corners,
        coltitle=black,
        fontupper=\small,
        enhanced,
        attach boxed title to top center={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
        boxed title style={
            colback=white,
            colframe=black,
            sharp corners,
            remember as={title #1},
        },
        title={#1},
        remember as={#1},
    }
  ,mybgbox/.style={
        colback=mybgcolor
      ,colframe=gray%red!50!black
      ,coltitle=black
      ,fontupper=\small
      ,enhanced
      ,attach boxed title to top left={
          xshift=5mm
        ,yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2
        }
      ,boxed title style={
            colback=white
          ,colframe=black
          ,sharp corners
          ,remember as={title #1}
        }
      ,title={#1}
      ,remember as={#1}
    }
}

\begin{tcbraster}[
  raster columns=1
,raster row skip=8mm
]
  \begin{tcboxedraster}[
    raster columns=1
  ,raster row skip=5mm
  ]{
    mybgbox={Lib}
  }
    \begin{tcboxeditemize}%
    [%inner boxes properties
      myraster=3
    ]{%outer box properties
      mybox={Client Layer}
    }
      \tcbitem Library 2-1
      \tcbitem Library 2-2
      \tcbitem Library 2-3
      \tcbitem Library 2-4
      \tcbitem Library 2-5
    \end{tcboxeditemize}
    \vspace*{.5cm}
    \begin{tcboxeditemize}%
    [%inner boxes properties
      myraster=3
    ]{%outer box properties
      mybox={Utility Layer}
    }
    \tcbitem Library 1-1
    \tcbitem Library 1-2
    \tcbitem Library 1-3
    \end{tcboxeditemize}
    \vspace*{.5cm}
    \begin{tcboxeditemize}%
    [%inner boxes properties
      myraster=3
    ]{%outer box properties
      mybox={Base Layer}
    }
      \tcbitem Library 1-1
      \tcbitem Library 1-2
      \tcbitem Library 1-3
    \end{tcboxeditemize}
  \end{tcboxedraster}
\end{tcbraster}

\tikz[remember picture, overlay]{
  \draw[-latex] (title Base Layer) -- (Utility Layer);
  \draw[-latex] (title Utility Layer) -- (Client Layer);
}

\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `raster of rasters`. See section ["14.6 Rasters inside Rasters"](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox#page=293). It's important to read it to understand what happens. You need a `tcolorbox` (`tboxedraster` in following code) inside the external `raster`.

In this case `raster row skip` can be applied to fix distance between rows, but as this option also affects inner boxes, a `raster row skip=2mm` has been included in `myraster` definition to keep default separation between inner rows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\tcbset{
    myraster/.style={
        raster columns=#1, 
        raster equal height, 
        raster row skip=2mm,
        size=small, 
        rounded corners, 
        frame hidden, 
        colback=gray,
        halign=center,
        raster halign=center,
    },
    mybox/.style={
        colframe=black,
        sharp corners,
        coltitle=black,
        fontupper=\small,
        enhanced,
        attach boxed title to top center={yshift*=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
        boxed title style={
            colback=white,
            colframe=black,
            sharp corners,
            remember as={title #1},
        },
        title={#1},
        remember as={#1},
    }
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=1, raster row skip=8mm]
\begin{tcboxedraster}[raster columns=1, raster row skip=8mm]{colback=red!30, colframe=red!50!black}
\begin{tcboxeditemize}%
[%inner boxes properties
    myraster=3
]{%outer box properties
    mybox={Layer 2}
}
\tcbitem Library 2-1
\tcbitem Library 2-2
\tcbitem Library 2-3
\tcbitem Library 2-4
\tcbitem Library 2-5
\end{tcboxeditemize}

\begin{tcboxeditemize}%
[%inner boxes properties
    myraster=3
]{%outer box properties
    mybox={Layer 1}
}
\tcbitem Library 1-1
\tcbitem Library 1-2
\tcbitem Library 1-3
\end{tcboxeditemize}
\end{tcboxedraster}
\end{tcbraster}

\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw[<-, line width=.5mm] (Layer 2)--(title Layer 1);
\end{document}
```

[image]